# How can I get a rails mounted engine to inherit http auth from an ActionController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there anyway to get a mounted engine to inherit from an application controller that enforces http auth? For example, I mounted [pg-hero](https://github.com/ankane/pghero) under my 'admin' namespace (so it's accessible via /admin/pghero); however, I would like for 'basic auth' to apply when it is accessed via its route URL.

I'm using the latest stable stable rails version, 4.1.5.

routes.rb

```
  namespace :admin do
    get "/" => "clients#index" #define root for /admin
    resources :clients, except: [:new, :create, :destroy] do
      member do
        patch 'update_status'
      end
    end

    # mount pg hero under admin namespace
    mount PgHero::Engine, at: "pghero"
  end
```

/controllers/admin/application_controllers.rb

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

http_basic_authenticate_with name: "XXX", password: "XXX"
protect_from_forgery with: :exception


end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basic auth should be done at a lower level than Rails and really isn't meant for this scenario.

Instead, you can basic auth protect using your web server, whether that be Apache, Nginx, or anything else. Basic auth is never a great solution for locking away production content and you should instead use a fully fleshed out authentication system.

In response to your question. pg-hero has it's own namespace and ideally doesnt interact with your application. If you must have this case (and I suggest you go with one of the suggestions above) you can class_eval the base controller class from the engine as a decorator and add the details there. I will leave figuring this out as an exercise for you.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I understand basic auth is not the most optimal approach, but addons like https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web use basic auth, and it would be nice to have a common authentication approach to these different addons.

Comment: It'd be better to not use basic auth in that case. And instead tie into warden which runs under the hood on devise. If you don't want to do this, and just accept the defaults given to you, that's fine. But don't think that warrants a good idea for the rest of your site. And as said before, dont do basic auth in the app. Do it in Nginx, you can do that for delayed_job web too.

Comment: Thanks @Senjai... My authentication is homegrown... so I don't use Devise.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up basic auth in PgHero by setting env variables, as described here:

https://github.com/ankane/pghero#security

Comment: Thanks - I'm familiar with the default security setup - but I wanted to leverage http_basic_authenticate_with